# Rails: has_many and belongs_to with same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have a resource named `Team` which belongs to a user (in `client_id`) and should have many users (in `users`) in a Rails 3 application.

How can I specify

```
belongs_to :user
```

and

```
has_many :users
```

in one model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `has_and_belongs_to_many` ?

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Many-to-many

EDIT:

It may work like this:

```
belongs_to :user # User is the owner
has_many :members, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "user_id"
```

Comment: I'm unsure if this can be achieved with HABTM since I need to tell my `Team` that the owner of the team is a user and the members are users. If I understand it correctly HABTM means that multiple users can belong to multiple teams.

Comment: I've edited my answer, I think what you are looking for is to build the association manually with a meaningful name

Comment: thank you Anand and Blake Simpson, I stuck with the solution Blake offered (because it is a little more intuitive in my case), but I appreciate both answers!

Answer (score 1):

```
 # in models/team.rb
class Team
  belongs_to :client, class_name: 'User' # @team.client
  has_many :users # @team.users
end
```